# I found this huge rock crystal by the river have no idea what it is?

Tags: geology

![crystal rock yelowish to red yellow to orange has 3 layers of crystal
)[image: both chunks of rock came from the same peace broke of a chunk of the smaller one is one that we started to polish has sharp crystal edges and it goes right thru the rock in huge vains][image: found by the river looks like foam yellow to dark red orange 3 layers of crystal then rock]

Comment: The smaler chunk is a peace we broke off and polshied a bit

Comment: In which part of the world was it found: country, region, geological setting such as river, mountains, next to the Blue Sky Mine that used to mine gold/zinc/ other metal.

Comment: I found it next to the north Saskatchewan river near drayton valley

Answer (score 2):

Your rock is probably a piece of a sedimentary concretion.  I have collected rocks that look very similar from western South Dakota.  The yellow crystals are most likely calcite.  The dark brown colored material is also probably calcite and but might be barite.

Acid testing using HCL should confirm if the yellow and brown area are calcite.
It will probably be difficult to perform an accurate specific gravity measurement for the rock.  My experience is that concretions are commonly quite dense (denser than calcite/dolomite) due to presence of denser minerals such as ankerite, dolomite, barite, celestite, fluorite, marcasite, pyite, sphalerite, siderite, wurzite, and galena as microscopic inclusions hidden within the matrix material.

[Concretions definition from wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concretion)